# How can I iterate over lists with tuples and use nltk.FreqDist for the whole structure

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to iterate over lists with tuples inside in order to use nltk.FreqDist and nltk.ConditionalFreqDist for the whole structure. The structure is like this:

> [[('minha', 'PROADJ'), ('infância', 'N'), ('na', 'ADV'), ('Bahia', 'NPROP'), ('era', 'V'), ('boa', 'ADJ'), ('mas', 'KC'), ('era', 'V'), ('sofrida', 'PCP'), ('também', 'PDEN'), ('né', 'IN'), ('doutor', 'N'), ('Oswaldo', 'NPROP')], [('porque', 'KS'), ('eu', 'PROPESS'), ('tinha', 'V')]]

I don't want the results by each list (two lists in the example, but I have a thousand of them), but by the whole structure. How could I do this? The following code only gives me the results by lists:

```
fd = []
cd = []
for tuple in list1:
    fd.append(nltk.FreqDist(tuple)) 
    cd.append(nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(tuple))
```

and I want the results for the whole structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to try flattening your list of lists:

```
from nltk import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist

l = [[('minha', 'PROADJ'), ('infância', 'N'), ('na', 'ADV'), ('Bahia', 'NPROP'), ('era', 'V'), ('boa', 'ADJ'), ('mas', 'KC'), ('era', 'V'), ('sofrida', 'PCP'), ('também', 'PDEN'), ('né', 'IN'), ('doutor', 'N'), ('Oswaldo', 'NPROP')], [('porque', 'KS'), ('eu', 'PROPESS'), ('tinha', 'V')]]
l_flat = [i for l_ in l for i in l_]

fd = FreqDist(l_flat)
cfd = ConditionalFreqDist(l_flat)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I also put an index to get the second element, so:  [l_flat = [i[1] for l_ in l for i in l_]

Comment: @JuniorCosta If you have more than 2 enclosures you may unwind any number of them by adding more cycles